# Java change worker threads amount

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am using ExecutorService to create a fixed thread pool and start several worker threads which listen for something to happen and then do their jobs.
However sometimes I would like to increase or decrease the amount of threads that are running at the same time in order to fine tune the perfomance of the app (without restarting the app or killing any currently running threads). 
Should I create my own thread pool or is there a way to have a pool with changing size that will handle the start/stop of the workers as necessary.

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a flexible size, you can accomplish this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However sometimes I would like to increase or decrease the amount of
>   threads that are running at the same time in order to fine tune the
>   perfomance of the app (without restarting the app or killing any
>   currently running threads).

If you mean dynamically changing using some tool or something then I am not sure but you can put some code logic to control.

You can use `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` and use `CorePoolSize` and `MaxPoolSize` properties to have **control over the thread pool**.

**corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize:**

- A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()).
- When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle.
- If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.

However before you decide I would recommend reading below excerpt from Java docs of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

> However, **programmers are urged to use the more convenient Executors**
>   factory methods Executors.newCachedThreadPool() (unbounded thread
>   pool, **with automatic thread reclamation**),
>   Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int) (fixed size thread pool) and
>   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() (single background thread), that
>   preconfigure settings for the most common usage scenarios.

**Code sample:**
Please refer below code sample. Most of the things you can understand by reading code and going through Java docs. However, something which may not be obvious is the fact that

- we have used `ArrayBlockingQueue` for getting an bounded queue of 20 capacity (*you can decide on queue capacity as per your requirement*). **So, once there are more than 20 tasks waiting in the queue, new threads will be created BUT upto maximum of maxPoolSize**.
- Based on load we are increasing the number of core pool threads, which means more threads will be process your tasks, so chances of tasks getting queue'ed up is less. But you can play with maxPoolSize as well.

You can read "Queuing" section of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and decide on some other queue, as per your requirement.

[**ThreadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(int)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize%28int%29)
Sets the core number of threads. This overrides any value set in the constructor. If the new value is smaller than the current value, **excess existing threads will be terminated** when they next become idle. If larger, **new threads will, if needed, be started to execute any queued tasks**.

```
    //Read Java docs for details about construcutor...
    ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 100, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20));
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do your task...
        }
    };

    executeTasks(poolExecutor, runnable, false, false); //Compute last 2 parameters as you need and pass on required values.

public static void executeTasks(ThreadPoolExecutor poolExecutor, Runnable runnable, boolean isUnderLoad, boolean isOverLoad){
    if(isOverLoad && isUnderLoad){
        //Handle this situation, this should not be allowed, probably a coding bug can result this...
    }
    poolExecutor.submit(runnable);
    if(isUnderLoad){
        poolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    }
    if(isOverLoad){
        poolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: The tasks are running infinitely as they are connecting to a queue and waiting for requests to process, so the native implementation may not be the way to go, however I will implement a custom task pool that will handle the threads in a similar way as the java api does and will send kill signals to them or start new threads when necessary.
Probably the executors can handle this type of situations but i don't want to rewrite the whole project just to add dynamic thread pools.

Comment: If you are going to design your own thread pool then there are lot of aspects you need to take care, and that's a bold and courageous move. In any case, if you have infinitely running tasks then one thing you will certainly need is `LinkedBlockingDeque`.

Answer (score 3):

[`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) lets you do that.  See [setCorePoolSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize%28int%29) and [setMaximumPoolSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPoolExecutor dynamically increases and shrinks the number of threads. Ensure that you set the pool size correctly. CorePoolSize defines the max number of threads that are spawned. MaxPoolSize comes in to play when BlockingQueue defined is of finite size. When you have a finite queue size, new threads are spawned for every new task submitted till it reaches corepool size. If the number of requests in the queue increment beyond the finite size of the queue new threads are spawned till they reach MaxPoolSize.